# how to dispaly path of options object enclosed between high double quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown below in the code, in the method `createOptionsFor` i create `options` object. when i print that `options` object to investigate its contents using `console.log` i get the following

```
&SUBSET=ansi('20191-10-05') // the value of `startDate` is 2019-10-05
```

what i am trying to achieve is, when i print the contents of the `options` object, i want to see the `&SUBSET=ansi(` contains the date enclosed between high double quotes as follows:

```
&SUBSET=ansi("0191-10-05")
```

is that possible? please let me know how to do it

**note**

```
please consider only the following part of the options object:

codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME + '"'+startDate+'"' + ')'
```

**my attempts**

i used to set the data to `codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME` dynamically as follows:

```
codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME + '"'+startDate+'"' + ')'
```

but then, when i print the contents of the options object, i get the following:

```
&SUBSET=ansi(%2220191-10-05%22)
```

i want when i print the contents of the `options` object to get the following:

```
&SUBSET=ansi("0191-10-05") Not &SUBSET=ansi('0191-10-05')
```

**options object:

```
 createOptionsFor(rasDaManLayer, startDate, wktEPSG32632, userName, password) {
    return this.options = {
        agent: this.agent,
        auth: userName + ':' + password,
        // auth: auth,
        protocol: codeDERes.PROTOCOL_HTTPS,
        host: codeDERes.HOST,
        path: encodeURI(
            codeDERes.PATH
            +codeDERes.SERVICE
            +codeDERes.VERSION
            +codeDERes.REQUEST
            +codeDERes.COVERAGE_ID + rasDaManLayer
            +codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME + '''+startDate+''' + ')'
            +codeDERes.SUBSET_CRS
            +codeDERes.CLIP + wktEPSG32632
            +codeDERes.OUTPUT_CRS
            +codeDERes.ENCODE_FORMAT_IMAGE
            +codeDERes.RANGE_SUBSET
        ),
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
}
```

**constants**

```
function define(name, value) {
Object.defineProperty(codeDERes , name, {
    value:      value,
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false
});
}
export let codeDERes = {};
define('SUBSET_TIME','&SUBSET=ansi(') //<<<<=====
```

Comment: Well `codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME + '"'+startDate+'"' + ')'` would actually work, but your code has `codeDERes.SUBSET_TIME + '''+startDate+''' + ')'`

Comment: @Bergi would you please have a look at the question again?i added a new section to it titled `my attempts`

Comment: `%22` is the [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) of `"` - it is not wrong, and should be understood by your server. But if you need to avoid it, then just don't use `encodeURI`. Rather, use `encodeURIComponent` on the individual parts such as `startDate`